# Create Unique Column in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have an SSIS package that takes a table and looks up a whole lot of other columns to end up with a dataset like:

```
ItemID | ProductGroupCode | Product Code
1      |  AAAA            |
2      |  AAAA            |
3      |  BBBB            |
4      |  BBBB            |
5      |  CCCC            |
```

ItemID is unique. I need to create a unique ProductCode by joining the ProductGroupCode to a 4 digit number starting at 1700.

So the data would look like:

```
ItemID | ProductGroupCode | Product Code
1      |  AAAA            | AAAA1000
2      |  AAAA            | AAAA1001
3      |  BBBB            | BBBB1000
4      |  BBBB            | BBBB1001
5      |  CCCC            | CCCC1000
```

However it also needs to check that the Product Code doesn't already exist in the products table. There is a real chance that Product Code AAAA1000 already exists. If that is the case then it should increase the Product Code.

I was able to do it with a cursor in SQL, the table "ProductImportHalfWay" is the dataset halfway through the SSIS package

```
DECLARE @ProductCode VARCHAR(10),
        @CurrentProductCode VARCHAR(10),
        @ItemID INT,
        @ProductNumber INT

SELECT @ProductNumber = 0, @CurrentProductCode = ''

DECLARE productGroupCodes CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR SELECT distinct ProductGroupCode, ItemID
FROM ProductImportHalfWay 
ORDER BY ProductGroupCode 

OPEN productGroupCodes
    FETCH NEXT FROM productGroupCodes INTO @ProductCode, @ItemID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @CurrentProductCode <> @ProductCode
        BEGIN
            SET @CurrentProductCode = @ProductCode
            SET @ProductNumber = 1699 --set to 1699 so that we can add 1 to get 1700
        END

        SET @ProductNumber = @ProductNumber + 1
        WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Product WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode + CAST(@ProductNumber AS VARCHAR(4)))
        BEGIN
            SET @ProductNumber = @ProductNumber + 1
            --print 'increase'
        END     

        UPDATE ProductImportHalfWay
        SET ProductGroupCode = @ProductCode + CAST(@ProductNumber AS VARCHAR(4))
        WHERE ItemID = @ItemID

        FETCH NEXT FROM productGroupCodes
        INTO @ProductCode, @ItemID
    END
CLOSE productGroupCodes
DEALLOCATE productGroupCodes
```

but I don't know how to put this in the middle of a data transformation (and I don't really want to output the "ProductImportHalfWay" table)

---

EDIT: extra Example
If ProductCode AAAA1000 already exists in the database, then the imported records sould come thorugh as

```
ItemID | ProductGroupCode | Product Code
1      |  AAAA            | AAAA1001
2      |  AAAA            | AAAA1002
3      |  BBBB            | BBBB1000
4      |  BBBB            | BBBB1001
5      |  CCCC            | CCCC1000
```

Comment: So you have AAAA1000 and AAAA1001 generated and AAAA1000 exists, what does AAAA1000 become? AAAA1002? Would it matter if it became AAAA9999? Is there any issue with BBBB1000 sharing the same numeric code with AAAA1000? What happens when you exhaust your 4 digit number pool? In short, could you further explain your business rules for generating product code?

Comment: added extra example for what happens when AAAA1000 already exists. It should just increase to AAAA1001. Each ProductGroupCode should start at 1000, so AAAA1000 and BBBB1000 should co-exist. The numbers need to increase sequentially, so you can't just jump to AAAA9999. There wont be a situation where we have more than 10000 products, so don't worry about exhausting the 4 digit number pool

Comment: Basically the product code is made up of a product type (e.g. AAAA) and a number. The Item ID is the identity column that we use in the database to refer to a product, but the business uses the product code (e.g. AAAA1000) to refer to a product. We are trying to import a lot of new products and need to create product codes that match the rule, but do not clash with any existing product codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best we've come up with is to do a data transformation to setup the record, save it to a temp table, run the SQL that I included in the question then run another data transformation reading from the temp table that finishes off the import